# Can Bitcoin mining with my current specs break my PC?

Tags: mining-hardware

I use the Windows Store app mining program. Will it harm my computer if I'm using the following specs:

Intel i5 3.2Ghz
NVIVIDA GeForce 730
8GB RAM
2TB Hard Drive

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: The answers to this question are subject to change often as hardware and software combinations are highly variable. Related: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5045/can-casual-people-still-mine-for-bitcoins-now-that-the-difficulty-is-much-highe

Comment: Related: [In the ASIC-age, is it worth starting mining Bitcoin at home?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/41276/5406)

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what "Windows Store app mining" is, but it may very well be a scam and malware, as it makes absolutely no sense whatsoever to mine Bitcoin on a PC. Malware can harm you and your computer.

If it's not malware, it will run your PC hot, causing more ware and tear and thus harming your PC by causing premature breaking of parts.

If nothing else, it will harm your wallet, as you'll be paying an increased electricity bill, while getting nothing in return.

In short: just uninstall whatever that thing is and check for malware some more. If you want to learn about real Bitcoin mining, you'll have to read up on the subject some more first.

Answer (score 0):

It won't break it, it will just go slower and consume more electricity. But you will get no Bitcoin at all. Mining with personal computers has been pointless for years. It is an ASICs game, I'm sorry.